# Trying to create & use a conan package: lib dir not set

Tags: cmake, conan

I created a conan package for a 3rd party tool. I'm trying to test it, and it doesn't seem to add the lib dir so the linker can't find the package's lib. Not sure how to debug it.

Here's the conanfile.py for the package ("hjson"):

```py
class HjsonConan(ConanFile):
    name = "hjson"
    version = "2.2"
    url = "https://github.com/hjson/hjson-cpp"
    license="MIT"

    # Optional metadata
    description = "hjson C++ json library"

    # Binary configuration
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    options = {"shared": [True, False], "fPIC": [True, False], "version": "ANY"}
    default_options = {"shared": False, "fPIC": True, "version": "2.2"}

    # Sources are located in the same place as this recipe, copy them to the recipe
    exports_sources = ("hjson-src/*")

    def source(self):
        # unpacks into ./hjson-src
        get(self,
            f"https://github.com/hjson/hjson-cpp/archive/refs/tags/{self.options.version}.tar.gz",
            destination='hjson-src',
            strip_root=True)

    def config_options(self):
        if self.settings.os == "Windows":
            del self.options.fPIC

    def layout(self):
        # Sets source=., build=build/Release, generators=build/generators
        cmake_layout(self)

    def generate(self):
        tc = CMakeToolchain(self)
        # Here is where to set CMake variables ("-DXYZ")
        tc.variables["HJSON_ENABLE_INSTALL"] = 1
        tc.generate()

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure(build_script_folder='hjson-src')
        cmake.build()

    def package(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.install()

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = ["hjson"]
        # these are the defaults, here for clarity
        self.cpp_info.includedirs = ["include"]
        self.cpp_info.libdirs = ["lib"]
```

Running `conan create .` works; it populates a subdir of my `~/.conan` with the lib and headers and other metadata.

So I try to use it, with this conanfile:

```py
from conan import ConanFile
from conan.tools.cmake import CMake, cmake_layout
from conan.tools.build import cross_building


class HJsonTestConan(ConanFile):
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    # VirtualBuildEnv and VirtualRunEnv can be avoided if "tools.env.virtualenv:auto_use" is defined
    # (it will be defined in Conan 2.0)
    generators = "CMakeDeps", "CMakeToolchain", "VirtualBuildEnv", "VirtualRunEnv"
    apply_env = False
    test_type = "explicit"

    def requirements(self):
        self.requires("hjson/2.2")

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

    def layout(self):
        cmake_layout(self)

    def test(self):
        if not cross_building(self):
            cmd = os.path.join(self.cpp.build.bindirs[0], "example")
            self.run(cmd, env="conanrun")
```

with this CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(PackageTest CXX)

find_package(hjson CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(example src/example.cpp)
set_property(TARGET example PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
include_directories(${hjson_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${hjson_LIB_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(example hjson)
```

but the link fails because it's not passing `-L<conanpath>` on the link line. Poking around, it looks like `hjson_LIB_DIRS` is not set in the generated `build/generators/hjson-config.cmake`:

```
set(hjson_VERSION_STRING "2.2")
set(hjson_INCLUDE_DIRS ${hjson_INCLUDE_DIRS_RELEASE} )
set(hjson_INCLUDE_DIR ${hjson_INCLUDE_DIRS_RELEASE} )
set(hjson_LIBRARIES ${hjson_LIBRARIES_RELEASE} )
set(hjson_DEFINITIONS ${hjson_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE} )
```

So where do I go to fix that? I did set the `cpp_info.libdirs` in the package, so not sure why it's not getting through to the generated config.

The created conan package looks like this, btw:

```
~/.conan/data/hjson/2.2/_/_/package/37c9d02f...91ef
├── conaninfo.txt
├── conanmanifest.txt
├── include
│  └── hjson
│     └── hjson.h
└── lib
   ├── hjson
   │  ├── hjson-config-version.cmake
   │  ├── hjson-config.cmake
   │  ├── hjson-release.cmake
   │  └── hjson.cmake
   └── libhjson.a
```

Comment: CMakeDeps is oriented to CMake targets. You should use `target_link_libraries(example PRIVATE hjson::hjson)` and remove both `include_directories` and `link_directories`

Comment: BTW, you can add this recipe to ConanCenterIndex too, in case you are interested. Please, read https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/docs/adding_packages/README.md in case you have some interest.

Comment: Thanks! Your fix worked. Just curious: where is the `hjson::hjson` cmake var created from the info in the cache? As for submitting, I think I'll wait til I'm more experienced with Conan before trying to submit anything. If anyone else is interested, feel free to copy from my recipe above.

Comment: ``hjson::hjson`` is not created in the cache, but in the consumer "generators" folder. The recipe ``self.cpp_info.libs = ["hjson"]`` is translated on the fly to every different generator in a different way. If you were using ``MSBuildDeps`` generator, it would create ``.props`` files for you to add to your VS project, containing the necessary definitions for VS for finding hjson.